# Can a bathtub work without a drain waste or removal shoe?

Tags: bathtub, drainage

I guess the drain waste or removal shoe was missing which I saw after trying to change out bathtub drain. Is this a really important part and is it difficult to install?

Comment: What part are you calling the shoe? I think of it as [the drain entrance body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3IQq.png). That's obviously critical.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's unclear what you're asking here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.